# css about fliped corner and affected level

Tags: css

Question 1:

Is css possible to make the corner of a img or a div to this?

I don't concern browser support problem, are any css1 or css2 or css3 can make this in easy way?

[image]

Question 2:

Can I prevent the css for deepLevel1 which not affect to deepLevel2, without adding any css to deepLevel2

I mean the css will only affect to own level, not deeper level

I only want abc is red, and 123 is still black color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#deepLevel1
{
    color:red;
}
#deepLevel2
{

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="deepLevel1">
    abc<div id="deepLevel2">123</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the flipped corner to animate?

Comment: You should not ask two unrelated questions in the same question. Next time, make two questions.

Comment: Cascading style sheets cascade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey now you can do easily as like this

check to this live demo http://jsfiddle.net/pkZ8G/1/

more info http://www.freshdesignweb.com/useful-example-css3-style.html

Answer (score 0):

Question 2:  You cannot prevent the `color` being applied without overriding it in your `deepLevel2` id style.